# Quasar App cloned repository launches on windows machine but not on new Mac

Tags: git, quasar-framework

I am moving to a Mac and using repository cloned from Github. This is a new Mac, if that matters. Just fixed npm permission issues. Here is what I did:

1. Installed npm
2. Installed git
3. Cloned the repository in VS Code
4. Ran "npm ci"

Here's what happens:

1. See the terminal output below.
2. See quasar info output below
3. The project shows a getPiniaStore error that doesn't exist when the cloned repository is ran on a windows machine.
4. On cleaning all store calls out of the router to avoid the above error, nothing renders and no errors are shown. The favicons are present, but that's the only thing I can see on the screen or dev tools.

I don't know if I should start building the app from a different file or if there are mismatched dependencies or what. Again, works perfectly on cloned repository on windows machine.

Package.json

> "dependencies": {
> "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
> "core-js": "^3.6.5",
> "firebase": "^10.0.0",
> "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
> "pinia": "^2.0.11",
> "quasar": "^2.6.0",
> "sitemap-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
> "vue": "^3.0.0",
> "vue-advanced-cropper": "^2.8.8",
> "vue-router": "^4.0.0"   },   "devDependencies": {
> "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
> "@quasar/app-webpack": "^3.0.0",
> "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-qpdfviewer": "^2.0.0-alpha.6",
> "eslint": "^8.10.0",
> "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
> "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
> "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
> "prettier": "^2.5.1"   },

TERMINAL OUTPUT

```
 Dev mode.................. spa
 Pkg quasar................ v2.12.2
 Pkg @quasar/app-webpack... v3.9.2
 Pkg webpack............... v5
 Debugging................. enabled

 Configured browser support (>= 86.90% of global marketshare):
 · Chrome for Android >= 114
 · Firefox for Android >= 115
 · Android >= 114
 · Chrome >= 105
 · Edge >= 111
 · Firefox >= 106
 · iOS >= 15.2-15.3
 · Opera >= 96
 · Safari >= 15.6

 App • Running "@quasar/qpdfviewer" Quasar App Extension...
 App • Extension(@quasar/qpdfviewer): Extending quasar.config.js...
 App Extension (qpdfviewer) Info: 'Adding qpdfviewer boot reference to your quasar.conf.js'
 App Extension (qpdfviewer) Info: 'Adding pdfviewer.sass css reference to your quasar.conf.js'
 App • Chaining "UI" Webpack config
 App • Extending "UI" Webpack config
 App •  WAIT  • Compiling of "UI" in progress...

 • Compiling:
 └── UI ██████████           46% building 2/3 entries 742/816 dependencies 100/306 modules

css warnings omitted
   
 App •  DONE  • "UI" compiled with success • 5144ms



 App •  READY  • Compiled: "UI"

 » App dir................... /Users/USER/Desktop/Coding/GITclones/PROJECT
 » App URL................... http://localhost:8080/
                              http://xxx
 » Dev mode.................. spa
 » Pkg quasar................ v2.12.2
 » Pkg @quasar/app-webpack... v3.9.2
 » Transpiled JS............. yes (Babel)

 App • Opening default browser at http://localhost:8080/
```

QUASAR INFO

> Operating System - Darwin(23.1.0) - darwin/arm64 NodeJs - 20.10.0
>
> Global packages   NPM - 10.2.3   yarn - Not installed   @quasar/cli -
> 2.3.0   @quasar/icongenie - Not installed   cordova - Not installed
>
> Important local packages   quasar - 2.12.2 -- Build high-performance
> VueJS user interfaces (SPA, PWA, SSR, Mobile and Desktop) in record
> time   @quasar/app-webpack - 3.9.2 -- Quasar Framework App CLI with
> Webpack   @quasar/extras - 1.16.5 -- Quasar Framework fonts, icons and
> animations   eslint-plugin-quasar - Not installed   vue - 3.3.4 -- The
> progressive JavaScript framework for building modern web UI.
> vue-router - 4.2.4   pinia - 2.1.4 -- Intuitive, type safe and
> flexible Store for Vue   vuex - Not installed   electron - Not
> installed   electron-packager - Not installed   electron-builder - Not
> installed   @babel/core - 7.22.8 -- Babel compiler core.   webpack -
> 5.88.1 -- Packs ECMAScript/CommonJs/AMD modules for the browser. Allows you to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be
> loaded on demand. Supports loaders to preprocess files, i.e. json,
> jsx, es7, css, less, ... and your custom stuff.   webpack-dev-server -
> 4.11.1 -- Serves a webpack app. Updates the browser on changes.   workbox-webpack-plugin - Not installed   register-service-worker -
> 1.7.2 -- Script for registering service worker, with hooks   typescript - 4.9.4 -- TypeScript is a language for application scale
> JavaScript development   @capacitor/core - Not installed
> @capacitor/cli - Not installed   @capacitor/android - Not installed
> @capacitor/ios - Not installed
>
> Quasar App Extensions   @quasar/quasar-app-extension-qpdfviewer -
> 2.0.0-alpha.6 -- QPdfviewer is an app extension for viewing PDF files
>
> Networking   Host - MINEs-Laptop.local   en0 - 192.168.1.102